# DNS system is failing to resolve domain names occasionally

Tags: networking, dns

I'm running Xubuntu…

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 17.04

$ uname -a
Linux intrepid 4.10.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 10:55:28 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

…and connecting through wireless network.

However, the DNS system is acting weird and it fails to resolve domain names occasionally.

When I'm trying to resolve some domain name manually it gives me the following error:

```
$ nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find google.com: REFUSED
```

Here's the list of all DNS servers configured on my computer:

```
$ nmcli device show wlp3s0 | grep IP4.DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.4.4
IP4.DNS[3]:                             8.8.8.8
```

But, when I try to resolve the domain name and tell it to use my router as a DNS server directly (which should be used automatically in the first place)  it works flawlessly:

```
$ nslookup google.com - 192.168.1.1
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.122.238
…
```

Why does it fail to resolve the domain names? What server is it trying to use by default?

My `resolve.conf` is looking like this:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Any hints would be highly appreciated, thanks!

---

And here's the [output of `$ systemd-resolve --status`](https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/79e2e9df856e585821e8533ca8abd8c3#file-systemd-resolve). The interface I'm using is `wlp3s0`.

Comment: Is your router configured as a firewall to block DNS requests?

Comment: @CharlesGreen It has SPI firewall enabled, but I can't see any settings related to DNS. Also, if it was the case then manual lookup through router's DNS should also be blocked, right?

Comment: Did you run `systemd-resolve --status` as suggested in the `resolv.conf` file? What is the output? Add that to your question.

Comment: If you use your router's DNS, then a seperate server within the router issues another call to the internet for DNS.  Please try to configure your router to allow port 53, for both TCP and UDP connections outbound from your network.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I don't think that ports are blocked, at least this problem is not permanent. It happens sporadically. Also the manual requests are always working, which means that requests are passing through all right. My guess is that something wrong with local DNS server (`127.0.0.53`) in Ubuntu. But I'm not sure how to debug this.

@Thomas It has a lot of output, I will try to do this when next "outage" will happen and will add the results to my question.

Comment: I've just added the output of `$ systemd-resolve --status` to the question.

Comment: I have this issue too, after a session to a VPN network, it seems like the local DNS service (on 127.0.0.53) still tries to resolve the hostnames for which the DNS server in the VPN network is authoritative to that DNS server inside the VPN network and that doesn't work anymore after a disconnect. It should try another DNS server as provided via another  network interface.

A permanent workaround that I use is:
`mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf_orig` 
`ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

This makes me suspect that this is due to a bug in **systemd-resolved**

Comment: Does this fix the issue? https://blobfolio.com/2017/05/fix-linux-dns-issues-caused-by-systemd-resolved/

Answer (score 2):

i did what @jringoot suggested in his comment:
`mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf_orig`
`ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`
which basically copies the original resolv.conf file and creates another one.

I examined it and it showed it was still using router dns.
so then I opened the file
`vim /etc/resolv.conf`
and edited the nameserver from the router dns to 1.1.1.1 (CloudFlare DNS)
i.e. fill it with:
`nameserver 1.1.1.1`

when i do a check using
`nslookup google.com`
it now shows it is using my specified DNS:
`nslookup google.com`
`Server:        1.1.1.1`
`Address:   1.1.1.1#53`

`Non-authoritative answer:`
`Name:  google.com`
`Address: 172.217.160.14`